What exactly is the role of the Lorentzian metric within spacetime?
I learned that twodimensional spacetime diagrams and fourdimensional spacetime manifolds are provided with Lorentzian (pseudo-Riemannian) metric. However, regarding a spacetime diagram with a light ray, I find only a Euclidean metric, because if it was Lorentzian, the lightlike light ray would be reduced to a point.
The problem does not disappear if I try to put a spacetime diagram into some abstracter form: The light cone of lightlike movements has always a non-zero length, the light cone seems to be a core element of spacetime.
By consequence, to all appearances, the Lorentzian metric is not part of spacetime, spacetime has Euclidean metric and the Lorentzian metric (such as the zero proper time of light rays) may only be calculated from spacetime.
Can someone give me a more precise (mathematical) formulation of the actual role of the Lorentzian metric within spacetime, ideally including the fact that spacetime itself is Euclidean?

Spacetime is non-Euclidean. In Euclidean space, null rays (i.e. light) travel at infinite speed, which is not what is observed. The Lorentzian metric best represents our flat spacetime. What is the specific problem you have with Lorentzian metrics?

That is what I learned, too. However, regarding a spacetime diagram with a light ray, I find only a Euclidean metric, because if it was Lorentzian, the lightlike light ray would be reduced to a point. - I need a more precise description of the role of Lorentzian metrics

I do not understand how you would reduce a light ray to a point in Lorentzian space. Any two events on a lightlike worldline have a proper distance of zero, yes, but that is exactly what is expected of Lorentzian spacetime - that is part of the reason why FTL travel in flat Lorentzian spacetime is impossible.

The proper time is zero, but the zero proper time does not appear in the spacetime diagram, it can only be found by calculation. In the spacetime diagram, the light ray has a non-zero length. This may seem to be a quite banal fact, but it is a property of all spacetime diagrams and spacetime manifolds with light cone.

I recommend asking your question without making false statements like “the fact that spacetime itself is Euclidean”. Those turn your post into an off-topic non-mainstream personal theory worthy only of closure. It’s OK to have trouble understanding spacetime, but it’s not OK to make up stuff.

Ghoster, did you read my question?

Of course I read it. You’re extremely confused. If your question doesn’t get closed for being non-mainstream, then perhaps you’ll get an answer than unconfuses you.

the lightlike light ray would be reduced to a point No. I think your confusion may arise from thinking that events in spacetime with a light-like separation, and therefore a zero spacetime interval between them, are the same event. They’re not. Clearly the emission of a photon is not the same event as the absorption of it. These two events happen at different places and different times, but they have zero spacetime interval between them.

That is right, but the Lorentzian spacetime interval of lightlike phenomena is zero. In contrast, the interval from A to B of a light ray has non-zero length, and for this reason it does not describe the Lorentzian zero spacetime interval. It reflects the Euclidean length between A and B.

Sorry, I can’t straighten out all of your misunderstandings here in comments.

@Moonraker The depiction of spacetime on paper does not mean that spacetime itself is Euclidean. The proper length of a lightlike worldline is zero even though its length on paper is not.

"I learned that twodimensional spacetime diagrams and fourdimensional spacetime manifolds..." -- already you're in trouble. Diagrams are diagrams. They may be at most graphical illustrations of mathematical objects, not the mathematical objects themselves, like for example, manifolds!

The point is that, unlike a Riemannian metric, the Lorentzian metric doe not determine the topology (i.e the open sets) of the space. Two distinct points can have zero proper time separation. The open sets are determined by the manifold structure (Hausdorf property etc)and the metric is an additional structure added to the manifold.

On a spacetime diagram, the area of the causal diamond of two events gives the square-interval between those events. Lightlike related events are distinct events  with a zero area causal diamond.


regarding a spacetime diagram with a light ray, I find only a Euclidean metric, because if it was Lorentzian, the lightlike light ray would be reduced to a point

This is not correct. The light cone of the origin is the locus of all events such that $$\Delta s^2=-c^2 \Delta t^2+\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2=0$$ from the origin.
This locus of events is not a single event. If we rearrange the equation we easily get $$c^2 \Delta t^2=\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2$$ which is clearly recognizable as a sphere of radius $c\ \Delta t$, not just a single point. The fact that all frames agree on the speed of light is thereby the same as the invariance of $\Delta s^2=0$.
In fact, your assertion is exactly backwards. If the metric were Euclidean $$\Delta s^2=c^2 \Delta t^2+\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2=0$$ then the locus would be a single event. In the Euclidean metric, if points $A$ and $B$ have zero distance between them then $A=B$, but that is not true with the Minkowski metric.

Can someone give me a more precise (mathematical) formulation of the actual role of the Lorentzian metric within spacetime, ideally including the fact that spacetime itself is Euclidean?

No. Spacetime is not Euclidean.

It is important not to confuse the map with the terrain. A spacetime diagram is just a map, and it captures many useful aspects of spacetime, but it is not itself spacetime.
Similarly the metric we use is a mathematical construct, chosen for its utility rather than being intrinsic to reality. Even in a flat Euclidean space there are times when an alternative metric is more useful (e.g. the taxicab metric $ds = |x| + |y|$ often gives a more practical sense of 2d distance within a city).
The Minkowski metric is far more useful for spacetime than the usual Euclidean metric, because (a) it is Lorentz invariant and hence agreed upon by all observers, and (b) gives a practically useful number, which for time-like separated events is the time between the events for an inertial observer present at both of them, and for space-like separated events is the distance between the events relative to an inertial observer for whom the events happen at the same time.
It is true that the Minkowski metric assigns 0 to the "distance" between light like separated events, which is awkward. But honestly, what frame independent number could you assign to such events? The elapsed time between a light signal's emission and reception can be made arbitrarily large or small by boosts. So assigning a "distance" of 0 is as good as anything else we could come up with.

You are confusing the geometry of spacetime with the geometry of a page in a book on which we draw diagrams to visualise 2-d spacetime. The geometry of the diagram on the page is Euclidean, the geometry of spacetime is not.
